# jQuery error. When I degug in firebug I get this error:

Tags: jquery, firebug

my code:

```
var custID = <?php echo htmlentities( $_GET['custID'] ); ?>;
```

I get error in firebug:

```
SyntaxError: syntax error [Break On This Error]       var custID = <br />
```

Please note: I am not passing a parameter custID.

Comment: in javascript, `var custID = ;` would be a syntax error, you'll need to set it to something by default, or not run that line of code if the parameter is not set.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but where's the jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify it as a string, if using `htmlentities()`:

```
var custID = '<?php echo htmlentities( $_GET['custID'] ); ?>';
```

It is also worth noting that you might need to add slashes to the string to prevent it from breaking out of the literal in JS:

```
var custID = '<?php echo addslashes(htmlentities( $_GET['custID'] )); ?>';
```

Comment: now I get the error: SyntaxError: unterminated string literal
[Break On This Error]  

var custID = '<br />

Comment: Then try adding `addslashes()` to your PHP.

Comment: Thanks any way I have worked it out, I viewed the source on the browser I am getting a PHP error, its sorted now. But you have been so helpful, so Ive selected your answer thanks.

Comment: No problem, I suspected that was the case.